# How do I configure System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection for a containerized LDAP server?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, openldap, directoryservices, c#-7.0

I've followed [this guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/run-openldap-server-in-docker-containers/) to setup an OpenLDAP server in a container. When I run the container with TLS/SSL set to *false*, as follows:

```
sudo docker run \
    --name openldap-server \
    --rm \
    --publish 389:389 \
    --hostname my.ldap.server.org \
    --env LDAP_ORGANISATION="My LDAP organization" \
    --env LDAP_DOMAIN="my.ldap.server.org" \
    --env LDAP_BASE_DN="dc=my,dc=ldap,dc=server,dc=org" \
    --env LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD="test" \
    --volume /data/slapd/database:/var/lib/ldap \
    --volume /data/slapd/config:/etc/ldap/slapd.d \
    --env LDAP_TLS=false \
    --detach osixia/openldap:latest
```

Then, in my C# 7.0 code, I'm able to connect just fine as my test user, as follows:

```
var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(serverIp, 389))
{
    AuthType = AuthType.Basic
};
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;

string username = "uid=test,ou=person,dc=my,dc=ldap,dc=server,dc=org", password = "test";
ldapConnection.Bind(new NetworkCredential(username, password));
```

But when I restart the OpenLDAP container with TLS/SSL enabled, as such:

```
sudo docker run \
    --name openldap-server \
    --rm \
    --publish 636:636 \
    --hostname my.ldap.server.org \
    --env LDAP_ORGANISATION="My LDAP organization" \
    --env LDAP_DOMAIN="my.ldap.server.org" \
    --env LDAP_BASE_DN="dc=my,dc=ldap,dc=server,dc=org" \
    --env LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD="test" \
    --volume /data/slapd/database:/var/lib/ldap \
    --volume /data/slapd/config:/etc/ldap/slapd.d \
    --volume /data/certificates:/container/service/slapd/assets/certs \
    --env LDAP_TLS_CRT_FILENAME=server.crt \
    --env LDAP_TLS_KEY_FILENAME=server.key \
    --env LDAP_TLS_CA_CRT_FILENAME=ca.crt \
    --detach osixia/openldap:latest
```

Then I don't know how to add all the required certificates to the *LdapConnection* in the C# code. I've gotten this far:

```
var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(serverIp, 636))
{
    AuthType = AuthType.Basic
    // AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate
};
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;

// var serverCrt = File.ReadAllText("<my certificate directory>/server.crt");
// var serverKey = File.ReadAllText($"<my certificate directory>/server.key");
// var serverCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(serverCrt, serverKey);
// var serverCertificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("<my certificate directory>/server.crt");
// var caCertificate = new X509Certificate("<my certificate directory>/ca.crt");

// connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((connection, serverCertificate ) => true);
// connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = delegate { return true; };

ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;

ldapConnection.Bind(new NetworkCredential("uid=test,ou=person,dc=my,dc=ldap,dc=server,dc=org", "test"));
```

How do I configure the code to connect with TLS/SSL when the OpenLDAP server expects both a server & a CA certificate (I think)? I don't think the solution is to install the certificates on my host machine because the code will run in a container and the certificates will be mounted at runtime.

Perpaps I made a mistake while generating the certificates. The *Common Name* (CN) of the Server certificate is *my.ldap.server.org*, and the CN of the CA is the username of the machine that hosts the OpenLDAP Container (but the username within the container is different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that I had to set an additional environment variable in the *docker run* command, namely *--env LDAP_TLS_VERIFY_CLIENT=never*

It then worked with this code:

```
var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(serverIp, 636))
{
    AuthType = AuthType.Basic
};
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = delegate { return true; };    
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;

ldapConnection.Bind(new NetworkCredential("uid=test,ou=person,dc=my,dc=ldap,dc=server,dc=org", "test"));
```